# Data not inserting in sqlite3 database using php

Tags: php, html, database, sqlite, pdo

Hy guys, I have a sqlite database named signup.db and a signup table in it and I have a php code of a signup page but it us not inserting any data on submit I also am not getting Amy error even on clicking on submit
*don't mind SQL injection this is just testing I will use SQL prepared statement when I make my next project
Code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//connection to sqlite3 database
$dir = 'sqlite: sign.db';
 $db = new PDO($dir) or die ("Unable to open");
//select table

//saving data
$email = $_POST["Email"];
$first = $_POST["First"];
$last = $_POST["Last"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];
$male = $_POST["Male"];
$female = $_POST["Female"];
$date = $_POST["Dateofb"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO Signup (First, Last, Email, Password, Male, Female, Dateofb) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$pass', '$male', '$female', '$date');";
$sql->execute();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"  >
<script src="index.js" ></script>
<title>Survey</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post"  >
<div class="container" >
<div class="form" >

<input type="email" class="first"  id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
<input type="text" class="second"  id="first" placeholder="First name" required="required">
<input type="text" class="last"  id="last" placeholder="Last name" required="required">
<input type="password" class="pass"  id="pass" placeholder="Password" required="required">

<div class="day" >

<p class="bd" >Birthday Date:</p>

<input type="date" class="date" id="date"  >

</div>
<div>
<div class="malee" >
<input type="checkbox" class="male" id="male"  >
<p class="mal" >Male</p>
</div>
<div class="femalee" >
<input type="checkbox" class="female" id="female"  >
<p class="fem" >Female</p>
</div>
</div>
<div >
<input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit"   >
</div>
<div class="acc" >
already have account <a href="#" >Login</a>
</div></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYkug.jpg)

Comment: To tell you guys I have a table with name signup in it a column with name signup and in it rows the name email etc

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. You should query on a db connection

> $db->exec($sql);

2. In $sql string

> $pass should be $password

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Signup (First, Last, Email, Password, Male, Female, Dateofb) 
VALUES ('$first', '$last', 
'$email', ******'$pass'*******, '$male', '$female', '$date');";
```

I created sandbox for you. Working fine . You can copy this code into a separate test.php file and try running it

Check this [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8039bf63ed3e7d9db8e05c475d884c9edd1b2260)

```
<?php 

try {
  $conn = new PDO("sqlite: sign.db");
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $email = "test2";
    $first =  "";
    $last =  "";
    $password =  "";
    $male =  "";
    $female =  "";
    $date =  "";
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Signup (
      First text NOT NULL, 
      Last text NOT NULL, 
      Email text NOT NULL, 
      Password text NOT NULL, 
      Male text NOT NULL,
      Female text NOT NULL,
      Dateofb text NOT NULL
    );"; 
    
    $conn->exec($sql);
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Signup (First, Last, Email, Password, Male, Female, Dateofb) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$password', '$male', '$female', '$date');";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully \n";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Signup";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        echo $row['Email']."\n";
    }
    
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

 ?>
```

Comment: It still didn't inserted data

Comment: Edited the answer. Can you try it And let me know the error if any

Comment: There is no error its just that the information is not inserting

Comment: Either data will be inserted or you will get an error. Unless until you share the full codes and error , we cant help you

Comment: Bro I am telling you there is no error and let me try the new code you send

Comment: I am getting this error after using your code ```syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH) in /storage/sdcard1/www/3/signup/index.php on line 19
```

Comment: Can you create a file called "test.php" and paste the code i shared above. And then run it and share the error

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' : This literally means you have a syntax error in php code block

Comment: Bro I pasted the code you gave and at line 19 its ``` } catch(PDOException $e) {```

Comment: @Forgechemist See the update answer.  Please create test.php file and paste new the code given above and try running it